# How to suppress/ignore tflint warnings

Tags: terraform, github-actions, lint

I am using tflint for the first time to scan my terraform code. For that I have created shell script to execute tflint command however, I am getting some [WARN] messages when tflint job is executed. I am not sure how they are generated. Is there a way to suppress it?

tflint command is getting executed successfully and also showing possible issues/notice in my terraform code.

I am using below Github workflow action;

```
      - name: Setup TFLint
        uses: terraform-linters/setup-tflint@v1
        with:
          tflint_version: v0.26.0

      - name: Lint Terraform Code
        run: scripts/tflint.sh
        shell: bash
        continue-on-error: false
```

".tflint.hcl" file ->

```
plugin "aws" {
  enabled = true
  version = "0.12.0"
  source  = "github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-aws"
}

rule "terraform_naming_convention" {
  enabled = true
}

rule "terraform_unused_declarations" {
  enabled = true
}

rule "terraform_deprecated_index" {
  enabled = true
}

rule "terraform_documented_outputs" {
  enabled = true
}

rule "terraform_documented_variables" {
  enabled = true
}

rule "terraform_typed_variables" {
  enabled = true
}
```

tflint.sh ->

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Scanning all files(*.tf) with tflint"
find * -name '*.tf' | grep -E -v ".terraform|.terragrunt-cache" | while read -r line; do
    tflint "$line" -f compact
done
```

Github workflow output showing [WARN] messages-->

[image]

Comment: v0.26.0 is kinda old (04 Apr 2021). Could you first try to upgrade to the latest v0.34.1 to rule out any old issues which have been already fixed by the devs?

Comment: Yes, I did try with version `0.34.1` but no luck. Actually, what I feel is that something causing due to my script?

Comment: Can you maybe add your Terraform code too? And do you use custom GitHub runners? I tested it on a private repo with the same tflint version, the same script and the same .tflint.hcl file without any issue.

Comment: That's strange. Well, not sure if has anything to do with the terraform code further referring this [Github issue](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/issues/1274).

Comment: Do you use the *azurerm* plugin? And if yes, which version of it? As it was not part of your .tflint.hcl posted here, i did not test it initially, but with this plugin i get the same error messages on my side.

Comment: I have used only *aws* plugin as mentioned in .tflint.hcl

Answer (score 12):

As of tflint `v0.39.3` [Ref](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/blob/v0.39.3/docs/user-guide/annotations.md)
You can use an the following annotation to inline-ignore rules.

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
    # tflint-ignore: aws_instance_invalid_type
    instance_type = "t1.2xlarge"
}
```

As of tflint `v0.40.0` [Ref](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/blob/v0.40.0/docs/user-guide/annotations.md) adds two more annotation styles.

```
# comma-sperated
# tflint-ignore: aws_instance_invalid_type, other_rule

# ingore all using keyword
# tflint-ignore: all
```

Different rules can apply to resource blocks or to the elements within.
Take `terraform_naming_convention` in the example below. This rule describes the terraform naming convention violation for the resource. To ignore this statement the directive is located above the block.

```
# tflint-ignore: terraform_naming_convention
resource "random_id" "bad-example" {
  # tflint-ignore: terraform_deprecated_interpolation
  prefix = "${local.prefix}"
  keepers = {
    id = "dev-test"
  }
  byte_length = 2
}
```

Comment: Oddly, I found that these annotations only worked if placed outside the resource block, not within it.

Comment: @james.garriss extended the example to show how different rules can apply to the elements or the resource.

Answer (score -1):

I've run into this with a terraform file that creates a dynamodb table, and none of the suggestions above work.  I've tried these both inside and outside of the resource block and they don't work:

```
# tflint-ignore: server_side_encryption
# tflint-disable: server_side_encryption
# tflint-ignore: all
```

The tflint project is currently at v0.47 and it probably shouldn't be used at this point.

Answer (score -4):

By the way, I have managed to suppress the warning messages by making use of null device `/dev/null` and redirected STDERR logs generated by script to `2> /dev/null`.

Final Code:

```
- name: Lint Terraform Code
  run: scripts/tflint.sh 2> /dev/null
  shell: bash
  continue-on-error: false
```